# How to see the live sites which is running on other devices connected to my router

Tags: networking, monitoring, router

Is there any software by which I can find out who is connected to my router and which sites he is surfing? Also the bandwidth of the network used by the device and the history so that I can monitor the other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Simply what you can do to find connected users: list `arp` when you connected to your router.

```
user@----:~# arp IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address   Mask     Device
192.168.1.128    0x1         0x2         9c:35:11:94:11:2a     *        br-lan
192.168.1.241    0x1         0x0         cc:3a:11:57:11:81     *        br-lan
```

to trace TCP traffic you can try to use `netcat` ('`nc`'), o (maby better) `tcpdump`. `port 80` - `http` traffic. `netstat` may help too.

You won't get the traffic each user eats. 
You can find what traffic was used per interface. e.g.

```
user@----:/tmp# ifconfig wlan1
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:11:B3:C6:11:08
          inet6 addr: fe80::6666:b3ff:fec6:fb08/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5690409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5434673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          **RX bytes:1156566484 (1.0 GiB)  TX bytes:1921837320 (1.7 GiB)**
```

Comment: Its not showing me the names of the current sites the connected devices are surfing.

Comment: It wont because it works in different OSI layer. It will show only IP's of web sites. You can sniff all the traffic with WireShark, but in that case you should make some kind of MIM (man in the middle) using additional hub.

Comment: Is there any third pary software which can help ?